# Network is connecting using Lan but WIFI is not found in the network devises

Tags: lan

I am using DLink 2750 router, problem is that the network is not visible in the WiFI netwoks. Using Lan is working but Wifi is not working on my laptop...please advise a solution

Answer (score 0):

run this command in command prompt ( press windowsKey + R , then type cmd and press eneter)

```
netsh wlan show networks
```

this command shows the networks which are available via wireless interface. (of course it works if your wireless adapter is installed correctly)

Comment: @siva it would be better to give more information. for example do your other devices can use WIFI properly? does your PC can connect to other WIFI routers? any further information is appreciated.